# What does this slicing mean [:, :, 0]?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

I am trying to understand [this code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/opt_flow.py#L39)

I can't get my head around what this line is doing. The flow variable is an array of flow vectors with one for each pixel in the image (so a 2d array).

`fx, fy = flow[:, :, 0], flow[:, :, 1]`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: See [numpy slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: I have read it and I think it says it returns the corresponding sub-array with dimension N - 1, but  I don't really understand what that means and was wondering if anyone could explain it in a different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us first simplify the expression. Your code:

```
fx, fy = flow[:, :, 0], flow[:, :, 1]
```

is equivalent to:

```
fx = flow[:, :, 0]
fy = flow[:, :, 1]
```

So now it boils down on what `flow[:, :, 0]`. It means that `flow` is a *numpy* array with at least three dimensions (let us define `N` as the number of dimensions). Then `flow[:,:,0]` is an `N-1`-dimensional array, where we pick `0` always as the third dimension.

In the context of **image processing**, an image is usually a 3d-array (given it has color) with dimensions `w` × `h` × `3` (three color channels). So here it means that `flow[:,:,0]` will generate a `w` × `h` *view* where for each pixel, we select the red channel (given the red channel is the first channel).

So if `flow` is a 5 × 4 × 3 matrix, like:

```
>>> flow
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35]],

       [[36, 37, 38],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47]],

       [[48, 49, 50],
        [51, 52, 53],
        [54, 55, 56],
        [57, 58, 59]]])
```

Then we will obtain for each 3-tuple the first element, making it:

```
>>> flow[:,:,0]
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [12, 15, 18, 21],
       [24, 27, 30, 33],
       [36, 39, 42, 45],
       [48, 51, 54, 57]])
```

and by querying `flow[:,:,1]`, we obtain:

```
>>> flow[:,:,1]
array([[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [13, 16, 19, 22],
       [25, 28, 31, 34],
       [37, 40, 43, 46],
       [49, 52, 55, 58]])
```

mind that these are **views**: if you alter `flow`, it will **have impact on `fx` and `fy` as well**, even if you did these assignments before.